# Can d3.js / JavaScript update a text value like in a chart?

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I've been searching around for a while now for a possible solution to this problem. I've created a bar chart for a company dashboard based on this graph.

http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/3887051

This is working great, however what I would like to do now is display some of the external data that I have in text underneath the graph so for example. "Total Sales Today = ......" instead of just a monthly graph.

So I guess I'm asking is there a way to do this in d3.js using a text element or anything similar? if not pointing me to something that can would be great. Ill also add that the data is coming from a csv.

This is the code:

```
var margin = {top: 20, right: 20, bottom: 30, left: 40},
width = 960 - margin.left - margin.right,
height = 500 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

var x0 = d3.scale.ordinal()
.rangeRoundBands([0, width], .1);

var x1 = d3.scale.ordinal();

var y = d3.scale.linear()
    .range([height, 0]);

var color = d3.scale.ordinal()
    .range(["#98abc5", "#8a89a6", "#7b6888", "#6b486b", "#a05d56", "#d0743c",  "#ff8c00"]);

var xAxis = d3.svg.axis()
    .scale(x0)
    .orient("bottom");

var yAxis = d3.svg.axis()
    .scale(y)
    .orient("left")
    .tickFormat(d3.format(".2s"));

var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
    .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
    .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
  .append("g")
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

d3.csv("data.csv", function(error, data) {
  var Names = d3.keys(data[0]).filter(function(key) { return key !== "Month"; });

  data.forEach(function(d) {
    d.Total = Names.map(function(name) { return {name: name, value: +d[name]}; });
  });

  x0.domain(data.map(function(d) { return d.Month; }));
  x1.domain(Names).rangeRoundBands([0, x0.rangeBand()]);
   y.domain([0, d3.max(data, function(d) { return d3.max(d.Total, function(d) { return     d.value; }); })]);

  svg.append("g")
      .attr("class", "x axis")
      .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
      .call(xAxis);

  svg.append("g")
      .attr("class", "y axis")
      .call(yAxis)
    .append("text")
      .attr("transform", "rotate(-90)")
      .attr("y", 6)
      .attr("dy", ".71em")
      .style("text-anchor", "end")
      .text("Sales Value £");

  var text = svg.selectAll("text")
      .data(data)
      .enter()
      .append("text");


  var Month = svg.selectAll(".Month")
      .data(data)
     .enter().append("g")
      .attr("class", "g")
      .attr("transform", function(d) { return "translate(" + x0(d.Month) + ",0)"; });

  Month.selectAll("rect")
      .data(function(d) { return d.Total; })
    .enter().append("rect")
      .attr("width", x1.rangeBand())
      .attr("x", function(d) { return x1(d.name); })
      .attr("y", function(d) { return y(d.value); })
      .attr("height", function(d) { return height - y(d.value); })
      .style("fill", function(d) { return color(d.name); });

  var legend = svg.selectAll(".legend")
      .data(Names.slice().reverse())
     .enter().append("g")
      .attr("class", "legend")
      .attr("transform", function(d, i) { return "translate(0," + i * 20 + ")"; });

  legend.append("rect")
      .attr("x", width - 18)
      .attr("width", 18)
      .attr("height", 18)
      .style("fill", color);

  legend.append("text")
      .attr("x", width - 24)
      .attr("y", 9)
      .attr("dy", ".35em")
      .style("text-anchor", "end")
      .text(function(d) { return d; });

});
```

If you need any more info just say

Cheers!

Comment: Do you want to change the x-axis label to read "Total sales today = ..." or do you want a label below the whole chart?

Comment: @JonathanLuckin below the whole chart

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your HTML file, create a div for your chart and a div below that for your label

```
<div id="chart"></div>
<div id="label"></div>
```

In your d3 code, instead of appending an svg element to the body, select the "chart" div and append an svg element to it.

```
var svg = d3.select("#chart").append("svg"). ...
```

Use that svg element to draw your chart like in your above code.

At some point in your code calculate the total sales for the day and create a variable called `totalSales`. You could do this by summing up the sales value when you draw the chart, but it doesn't really matter as long as `totalSales` is calculated.

Create another svg element on the "label" div

```
var svgLabel = d3.select("#label").append("svg") ...
```

Use this svgLabel to write a text element with `totalSales` as the text attribute.

```
svg.append("text")
...
.text(totalSales);
```

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand 100% the last few lines. This is my whole bit : `d3.csv("OrderValueToday.csv"), function(error, data){
  var svgLabel = d3.select("#label") .append ("svg")
  svg.append("text")
    .text(totalSales);
}` will this work if I'm loading another external csv in addition to the one building the graph. This value will be updated on the fly like the graph so the value will also be changing

Comment: Just keep track of the totalSales whenever you add/remove data. Either bind the totalSales data to the label div, or do something like `var text = svg.append("text")...` and whenever you load another csv just do something like `text.text(totalSales);`

Comment: I'm completely confused now :/ If you would be able to break it down to what is actually doing from getting the one value from the csv by doing `d3.csv (OrderValueToday.csv)...` then after that stage I'm just lost now...  in what order and where am I doing the other steps . this is what I've managed so far however it's not doing anything  - `d3.csv("OrderValueToday.csv"), function(error, data){   
  var svgLabel = d3.select("#label").append("svg") 
}

  var totalSales = svg.append ("text")
      .text(totalSales);`  Thanks for the help so far!

Comment: Create your totalSales variable to equal zero before loading in the csv. While loading in the csv, sum up the sales data into the totalSales variable. When the csv is done loading, totalSales contains the right amount. Create your svg element on the label div, and then append a text element on it with totalSales as the text

Comment: Thanks so much for the help! Just a quick little question I've got my csv linked and the data is loaded into the browser when I've appended a h2 and then inserted a text string display whatever has been loaded into the totalSales variable in the browser it just displays `[object Object]`. In firebug the correct data has been pulled from the csv. This is the code `d3.csv("OrderValueToday.csv", function(today) {
    console.log(today);

    var totalSales = today

    var svgLabel = d3.select("#label").append("h2")
      .text (totalSales)
});`

Comment: `today` is returning an array of the csv data. `totalSales` must be the sum of each sale of each element in `today`. Debug and look at `today` to see what the variables are called. Loop through it and sum up the correct attribute into `totalSales`

Comment: Just got back into work today but there is no sum because the data from `totalSales/today` has already been summed and exported for the sql database so the csv just displays `Today` as a heading and for example `100000` for the actual value for the total sales.`TotalSales` is just a variable = `today` which I then later appened a text element and call the varible `totalSales` and it returns [object Object] on the webpage. When I've de-bugged `today` in Firebug it just returns `[Object { Today="20000"}]`. Thanks for your help so far you have been a godsend. Cheers

Comment: This is the code on jsfiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/C6GsP/3/ however it wont create the graph as it referencing files that are stored locally because the machine isnt going to be online.

Comment: It looks like the variable `today` does not contain the value that you are looking for, since it is an object. The property `Today` contains the number. Try totalSales.Today instead of totalSales.

Comment: I asked another question and tried to explain as best as I could and they came up with this `d3.csv("OrderValueToday.csv", function(obj) { 
   var totalSales = obj[0].Today;
   svgLabel = d3.select("#label").append("h2")
     .text(totalSales);
});`  Thanks ever so much for your help even with everything you helped me out loads even with the scraps of infomation I was giving you